# PostgreSQL Temporary Column vector

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I run `select 1`, the result is:

[image]

When I run `select 1,2`, the result is:

[image]

Which query I should use if I want to have sth like this:

[image]?

Comment: You need to use table value constructor. Try the below code
`SELECT * FROM (VALUES(1),(2)) t(number_column)`

Comment: `select * from generate_series(1,2)`